# Converting PDF to string

Tags: php, pdf, file-conversion

How read PDF file and put content into string? Using PHP language.

Comment: Use [`file_get_contents`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you need the raw binary data or update your question and tell us what you really want.

Comment: I need get clean text from pdf files. When i get text from pdf files I need insert this text in DB.

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like pdftotext which comes with the Xpdf package on linux. The popen command can then be used to pipe the output of pdftotext into a string:

```
$mystring = "";
$fd = popen("/usr/bin/pdftotext blah.pdf","r");
if ($fd) {
    while (($myline = fgets($fd)) !== false) {
        $mystring .= $myline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Download link for xpdf: https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html and link to popen: http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Answer (score 0):

Install APACHE-TIKA on your server.
APACHE-TIKA support more then pdf files.
Install guide:
http://www.acquia.com/blog/use-apache-solr-search-files

and final code is easy:

```
$string = "";
$fd = popen("java -jar yourpathtotika/tika-app-1.3.jar -t yourpathtopdf/sample.pdf","r");
while (!feof($fd)) { 
$buffer = fgets($fd, 4096); 
$string .= $buffer;
}
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP class that is available here :

http://www.pdftotext.eu

This is a public domain PDF text extractor entirely written in pure PHP, meaning that you do not need to rely on external commands. It provides a simple interface to retrieve text :

```
include ( 'PdfToText.phpclass' ) ;
$pdf = new PdfToText ( 'mysample.pdf' ) ;
echo "PDF contents are : " . $pdf -> Text . "\n" ;
```

Comment: Dead link, do you mean https://www.pdftotext.com ?
I can't find the class you talked about