# AJAX POST to download and upload PDF file

Tags: php, ajax, pdf

I would like to write a chrome extension that downloads PDF file from a website accepting POST requests, and upload the PDF file to my localhost server. Here's my attempt:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/download.action',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/getpdf.php',
                data: response,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
                processData: false,
                crossDomain: true
            });
        }
    });
```

From the console I observed the response of the download ajax request, it's a binary content beginning with "%PDF-1.7.%...", seems reasonable. Then in localhost server side, I use some simple PHP code to save the PDF file:

```
<?php
$raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$f = fopen('test.pdf', 'w');
fwrite($f, $raw_data);
fclose($f);
?>
```

File is saved. But the saved PDF file can't be opened by Adobe Reader (file is damaged), and the file size is about 2 times larger than the original one.

I checked the binaries of the saved PDF file and the original one by `vim -b`, here're the first 10 lines:

The original one:

```
0000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0a25 e4e3 cfd2 0a36  %PDF-1.7.%.....6
0000010: 2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c2f 5479 7065 2f58   0 obj.<</Type/X
0000020: 4f62 6a65 6374 0a2f 5375 6274 7970 652f  Object./Subtype/
0000030: 466f 726d 0a2f 4242 6f78 5b30 2030 2035  Form./BBox[0 0 5
0000040: 3935 2e32 3736 2038 3431 2e38 395d 0a2f  95.276 841.89]./
0000050: 5265 736f 7572 6365 733c 3c2f 584f 626a  Resources<</XObj
0000060: 6563 743c 3c2f 496d 3020 3720 3020 522f  ect<</Im0 7 0 R/
0000070: 496d 3120 3820 3020 522f 496d 3220 3920  Im1 8 0 R/Im2 9 
0000080: 3020 523e 3e2f 436f 6c6f 7253 7061 6365  0 R>>/ColorSpace
0000090: 3c3c 2f43 5330 2031 3020 3020 522f 4353  <</CS0 10 0 R/CS
```

The saved one:

```
0000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0a25 efbf bdef bfbd  %PDF-1.7.%......
0000010: efbf bdef bfbd 0a36 2030 206f 626a 0a3c  .......6 0 obj.<
0000020: 3c2f 5479 7065 2f58 4f62 6a65 6374 0a2f  </Type/XObject./
0000030: 5375 6274 7970 652f 466f 726d 0a2f 4242  Subtype/Form./BB
0000040: 6f78 5b30 2030 2035 3935 2e32 3736 2038  ox[0 0 595.276 8
0000050: 3431 2e38 395d 0a2f 5265 736f 7572 6365  41.89]./Resource
0000060: 733c 3c2f 584f 626a 6563 743c 3c2f 496d  s<</XObject<</Im
0000070: 3020 3720 3020 522f 496d 3120 3820 3020  0 7 0 R/Im1 8 0 
0000080: 522f 496d 3220 3920 3020 523e 3e2f 436f  R/Im2 9 0 R>>/Co
0000090: 6c6f 7253 7061 6365 3c3c 2f43 5330 2031  lorSpace<</CS0 1
```

It seems some words are changed (maybe charset problem?)

Any hints about this?

Comment: *maybe charset problem* - yes, bytes > 128 are replaced by the [Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), efbfbd in UTF-8. A PDF is binary data, though, so no charset-related replacements should happen at all. Try adding `b` (binary) to the `fopen` mode.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I tried with adding `b` but the problem remains. May be the problem is in javascript side?

Comment: *May be the problem is in javascript side* - probably yes. Your hex dumps definitively look like some step inbetween treated the PDF as ASCII text (thus replacing every byte >127). Which step it is, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that meets my requirements.

As mentioned by @mkl, there's some replacement to `UTF-8` on the original PDF binary data, but we don't know in which step this replacement happens. So I start to search about sending/receiving binary data instead of strings, and I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), which introduced a feature called "arraybuffer".

According to the article above I changed my js function to this and it works:

```
var form = $('<form method="post"></form>');
for (var i in data) {
    form.append('<input name="'+i+'" value="'+data[i]+'" />');
}

data = form.serialize();

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open('POST', 'http://example.com/download.action', true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
    if (arrayBuffer) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost/getpdf.php', false);
        xhr.send(arrayBuffer);
    }
};

oReq.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this way to read pdf text and then write it as your new pdf file

[how to get text from pdf file and save it into DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264194/how-to-get-text-from-pdf-file-and-save-it-into-db)