# How to get a selected text of a pdf which is inside an iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

How to get a selected text from pdf in an iframe?

[image]

This is my Project example how to get the selected text from pdf in an iframe and i want it to copy it in the text field by clicking a button.

Comment: It looks like the image is scanned and added to the pdf as an image and not as text.  If this is the case, good luck!  Not only do you need to extract the image from the PDF, but you will need some OCR too.. From the looks of the upload, OCR won't help much anyway.. Start Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780697/php-pdf-to-string

Comment: Sorry Now could you suggest me a solution for this pdf.